# Create a Timestamp without timeZone

Tags: java, jdbc, timezone, timestamp

How can I create a `java.sql.timestamp` without timezone (i´m getting `2007-09-23T10:10:10Z` and I pretend `2007-09-23T10:10:10`).

I try:

```
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("2007-09-23 10:10:10");
```

but in debug i saw that the cdate is `2007-09-23T10:10:10.000+0100` instead of `2007-09-23T10:10:10`

Answer (score 16):

A Timestamp doesn't have a timezone. When you display the timestamp as a String, it displays a time and mentions the timezone, because else you couldn't know what time it represents. And it chooses to use the default timezone (yours), because that's the one you're the most familiar with.

Saying, it's 12:00:00 doesn't mean anything. Saying it's 12:00:00 in your timezone means something. But the timestamp only contains an instant in time. You may display this instant in time in any time zone you want using a DateFormat.

Note: `Timestamp.valueOf("2010-10-23 12:05:16");` means "create a timestamp with the given time *in the default timezone*".

Comment: That means that there isn´t a way to say that a don´t want the default timezone(or the same using a Date)? I pretend to ignore the Z in "23T10:10:10Z".

Comment: Use a DateFormat, set its time zone and pattern to the ones you want, parse your date/time String, and instantiate the Timestamp with the milliseconds from the Date. To display the timestamp, instantiate a DateFormat, set its time zone and pattern to the ones you want, and format the timestamp.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

> … can I create a java.sql.timestamp without timezone …

No, you cannot. Wrong class. Use `java.time.LocalDateTime` instead.

## Details

A `java.sql.Timestamp` is the wrong class to use. It represents a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

If you want a date with time-of-day irrespective of time zone or offset-from-UTC (so, *not* a moment), use another class that is fit-for-purpose.

By the way… The `java.sql.Timestamp` is a terrible old class badly designed, and was supplanted years ago by the class `java.time.Instant` (always in UTC) or alternatively `java.time.OffsetDateTime` if set to an offset of UTC.

## `LocalDateTime`

The proper class for a date with time-of-day without any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC is [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

As noted above, this means this class is *not* a moment, *not* a point on the timeline, and should *not* be used to track actual points of time when an event happened in some place.

## `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`

In a SQL-standard compliant database such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), use a column of data type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` (not the `WITH` type).

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

And…

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).