# Oracle DB Timestamp to Java Timestamp : Confusion

Tags: java, oracle, timestamp, gmt

I'm struggling from a couple of hours to understand what's going on with the `TimeStamp`s in my code.

Both the Oracle DB and the java application are in PDT

Select from DB:

```
select id, time_stamp from some_Table where id = '3de392d69c69434eb907f1c0d2802bf0';
3de392d69c69434eb907f1c0d2802bf0    09-DEC-2014 12.45.41.354000000 PM

select id, time_stamp at time zone 'UTC' from some_Table where id = '3de392d69c69434eb907f1c0d2802bf0';
3de392d69c69434eb907f1c0d2802bf0    09-DEC-2014 12.45.41.354000000 PM
```

The field in the Oracle database is `TimeStamp`, hence no timezone information is stored.

```
Timestamp dbTimeStamp = dbRecord.getLastLoginTime();
System.out.println(dbTimeStamp.toString()); // 2014-12-09 12:16:50.365
System.out.println(dbTimeStamp.getTime()); // 1418156210365 --> Tue Dec 09 2014 20:16:50 UTC?
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime()), `getTime()`

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
>   represented by this Timestamp object.

Why are `8 hours (PDT - UTC)` of extra time added to the response of `getTime()` ?

Comment: Because as you'll notice from the text you quoted: `since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`. Notice the `GMT` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers above and the references on SO. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8655522/174184) finally helped me in understanding where I was going wrong in understanding TimeStamps.

Qouting from the linked answer

```
Note: Timestamp.valueOf("2010-10-23 12:05:16"); means "create a timestamp with the given time in the default timezone".
```

TimeStamp represents an instant of time. By default, that instant of time in the current Timezone.

The timestamps being **written** to the DB were UTC instants. i.e. current UTC time was being written. Hence, no matter where the application was deployed, the value being written to the DB was the same TimeStamp.

However, while reading the TimeStamp generated assumes the default TimeZone as read from the deployment JVM. Hence, the value read was the instant in PST timezone. The actual UTC Value being 8 hours more than the PST time. Hence, the difference.

`TimeStamp.getTime()` returns milliseconds from UTC.
`TimeStamp.toString()` returns the representation of time in the current `TimeZone`. Thanks @marko-topolnik

To take an example,

- Value in the DB : `2014-12-09 12:16:50.365`
- When this value is read in a TimeStamp, the instant is `2014-12-09 12:16:50.365` in PST
- Convert this to UTC, it would be `2014-12-09 20:16:50`

Hence, the solution was to add the `TimeZone` offset to the values read from the database to get the instants as `UTC` TimeStamps.

The key here was "`TimeStamp is a time instant without TimeZone information. The timestamp is assumed to be relative to the default system TimeZone.`" - It took me a really long while to comprehend this.

Answer (score 4):

`TimeStamp.toString()` internally uses `Date.getHours()` whose javadoc states:

> Returns the hour represented by this Date object. The
>        returned value is a number (0 through 23)
>        representing the hour within the day that contains or begins
>        with the instant in time represented by this Date
>        object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

So `toString` is using your local time zone whereas `getDate` doesn't.

Comment: Does this mean that the absolute UTC time here is Tue Dec 09 2014 20:16:50 UTC (the value of the field from the database)?

Comment: It seems so. I don't know why the SQL select statement shows differences in minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 3):

These two are consistent with each other. The `getTime()` method gives you the absolute millicecond value, which you chose to interpret in UTC. The `toString()` method gives you that same millisecond value interpreted in the associated timezone. So it is not `getTime()` which is adding the time, but `toString()` which is subtracting it. This is not really documented, but that is how it behaves.

The most important takeaway should be not to rely on `Timestamp.toString` because it is misleading. The whole timezone mechanism within `Date` (and `Timestamp` is a subclass) has been deprecated a long time ago. Instead use just the `getTime()` value and have it formatted by other APIs, such as Java 8 Date/Time API.

#### Update

Apparently, the `toString()` output is actually the correct one, which for me is just one small addition to the thick catalog of all things wrong with Java's date/time handling. You probably receive the timestamp from the database as a formatted string, not the millisecond value. JDBC then parses that into a millisecond value according to the timezone associated with the `Timestamp` instance, such that the output of `toString()` matches what was returned by the database, and the actual millisecond value being secondary.

Comment: Does this mean that the absolute UTC time here is `Tue Dec 09 2014 20:16:50 UTC` (which is not consistent with the information I have)? I have added a select from the DB as well.

Comment: How can you be sure that output from Oracle isn't adapted to its default timezone?

Comment: I am assuming that because when I executed a select with `at time zone 'UTC'` `-->` It gave the same result.

Comment: To make sure this really proves it, try again with `at time zone 'PDT'`. I would also try casting the timestamp as a number, to get the raw value. If it does prove it, then there may be problems interpreting the value at the JDBC side.

Comment: Yes, it returns the same result with `PDT`. What could be wrong here?

Comment: I can only guess what Oracle's semantics are for that expression. My guess would be that it has something to do with that column being "without timezone". Anyway, are you sure you have an actual problem? If you have the correct numeric value stored, and have it correctly transferred to a Java Timestamp, then it's just up to correctly interpreting it within Java.

Comment: "Correctly transferred to Java Timestamp" - I executed the same code from 2 different geographies and the value of `dbTimeStamp.getTime()` is different (connecting to the same DB). The translation happens via Hibernate JPA. The locale offset is being used in the translation is my guess.

Comment: Sounds like the typical java timezone nightmare. I guess we can assume that the DB responds the same, and with a *string*, which Hibernate then parses into the millisecond value by using the default timezone. Maybe then what is consistent is the `toString` output (which is the exact opposite of what I would consider sane).